# How can i return arrays?

Tags: java

First, how can I return an array, and second I dont understand the .class expected.  I have questions posted in the code comments:

```
public static int[] histograma(int[] notas, int[] histo) {
    int cont = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 11; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
            if (j == notas[i]) {
                cont++;
            } else
                System.out.print("");
            histo[j] = cont; //Can i call a array like this?
        }
    }
    return histo[]; //i want to k how can i return a array and here say .class   expectd

}
```

---

Since this question has not been received very well by the community i need to ask another thing and i can only by re-edit:

I have `histo[]={1,4,5,6,8}`.

how can i make `System.out.print("*")` repeat first `histo[0]` times, `histo[1]` times ,... , `histo[4]` times all at once?

Comment: `return histo;`  You don't use brackets when referring to the whole array.

Comment: And what is the goal of this methid ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  You seem to have edited out the code from the original question after there was an answer in place.  Please don't do that, as it can make it hard for future readers to understand the existing answers.  You might want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, as one of the main benefits of SO is for future readers.

Comment: i know that,but since i had another question and my first one receive to many dislikes i cant do another question in the next 3 days, and i have test tomorrow,so...

Comment: I understand how you feel.  However, SO isn't a good forum for [urgent questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) but I have proposed an edit that restores the original context along with the extra question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Return `histo` like this:

```
public static int[] histograma(int[] notas, int[] histo){
     // code
     return histo;
}
```

Comment: No, it says int[] cannot be converted to int.What is meaning of .class expected